# Parts of TCP packet loss

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, boost-asio

I was writing a TCP server. I works fine on localhost. When I deploy it remotely some bytes are lost on their way to the destination.

I used netcat on localhost and remotely and made a diff of the two outputs and the lost bytes are deterministic.

So I doubt it is packet loss since it's very unlikely the same packet would get lost.

I tried to reduce the size of my writes on the socket to 1000 bytes but I still get this problem.

Are there any common reasons for this kind of errors ?

I could post the code but it's just a socket.send from the Boost asio library. I'm not sure the error comes from the code otherwise it would not work on localhost.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Tcp is loseless. It is in the spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793. Are you sure you are using tcp or the problem is elsewhere

Comment: The most usual reason for that is failing to check the return of `send()`. If you call `send(sck, data, 1000, 0)`, it returns `990` and you fail to check the return value and resend the remaining 10 bytes, then you will lose them. The same is true for `recv()`.

Comment: @Hd Heal I know it is loss less. That's why I'm asking here

Comment: @rodrigo . Why boost:asio not handling this kind of things. I mean who wouldn't want to resend their data ?

Comment: @DARK_DUCK: I was talking about `send()` in general, not asio. But from the doc: _The `send` operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer. Consider using the `async_write` function if you need to ensure that all data is written before the asynchronous operation completes._

Comment: @DARK_DUCK: But answering to your question. Imagine that you are sending 1GB of data. You will probably want some progress feedback while the data is being sent.

Comment: It's working fine with async_write (as soon as I don't interleave writes). Thank you. I can't accept your answer it's a comment :/

Comment: @DARK_DUCK: Ok, I've written an answer, with some additional information.

Comment: @rodrigo I disagree. The most usual reason is errors in the receiving code. `send()` sends everything in blocking mode unless there has been an interrupt.

Comment: @EJP: Maybe that is the norm. But I recall doing experiments in MS-Windows a few years ago (was it XP?) and in cases of network congestion `send()` sometimes returned less bytes than requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending data using a socket and function `send()` it returns the number of bytes actually sent, which may be less than the amount you pass to the function.

If you use blocking I/O, sometimes a function like this is used:

```
ssize_t send_all(int socket, const void *data, size_t len)
{
    while (len > 0)
    {
        ssize_t r = send(socket, data, len, 0);
        if (r < 0)
        { //you could also return -1 on EINTR
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        len -= r;
        data = (const char*)data + r;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Since you are using `boost::asio`, not raw sockets that approach is not useful. But at the [async_send](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send/overload2.html) documentation you get exactly what you need:

> The send operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer. Consider using the [`async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html) function if you need to ensure that all data is written before the asynchronous operation completes.